# Add \ in text where ' is found

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm making app, which needs to save post details in SQLite, and that post receives user input, like user text.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: pet.adoption.world.solutions, PID: 1500
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "s": syntax error (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Trading_info_post(NAME , PHONE , EMAIL , TITLE , PUBLISH_DATE,DESCRIPTION , TO_LOCATION , MODE_OF_TRAVEL , AVAILABILITY , DATE_OF_TRAVELING , PLANNED_TIME_COMING_AT_LOCATION , MAP , FROM_LOCATION , PASSING ) VALUES ('19.12.2019 22:00','01.01.2020 15:00','AD','HR,DE','ME','Adoption is a process whereby a person assumes the parenting of another, usually a child, from that person's biological or legal parent or parents. Legal adoptions permanently transfers all rights and responsibilities, along with filiation, from the biological parent or parents. /n In many jurisdictions the adopted person's full original birth certificate is cancelled and replaced with a fabricated post-adoption birth certificate which states that the child was born to the adoptive parents. This deception, when carried out, may continue with the adopted person for life and can be the cause for many well documented traumas experienced by the adopted person, including loss of identity, family history, culture, biological family (including not only biological parents but also siblings and extended family), family medical history and records, and increased risk of suicide, homelessness, incarceration, PTSD, depression, and anxiety. /n Unlike guardianship or other systems designed for the care of the young, adoption is intended to effect a permanent change in status and as such requires societal recognition, either through legal or religious sanction. Historically, some societies have enacted specific laws governing adoption; where others have tried to achieve adoption through less formal means, notably via contracts that specified inheritance rights and parental responsibilities without an accompanying transfer of filiation. Modern systems of adoption, arising in the 20th century, tend to be governed by comprehensive statutes and regulations.','master.dev.man@gmail.com','available','MNE - USA','11.11.2019','https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Tbutp40nzFMZE12Nzhqm1VMrceM13cBj&usp=sharing','with car','Igor Lerinc','+38267395564');, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:906)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:517)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:63)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1763)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1689)
    at pet.adoption.world.solutions.Database.Database.savePost_trading_info(Database.java:101)
    at pet.adoption.world.solutions.Trading_info_posts_details$1$4.onClick(Trading_info_posts_details.java:207)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5338)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21539)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:819)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:210)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5982)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742)
```

With SQLite i get exception when query is trying to put text in database, because as i found out [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36674726/11441494) it throws me exception because there is ' , so SQL think it is end of statement, so  \ needs to be added in front of ' sign to prevent error.

**How to add \ in front of ' when code detects ' sign.**

So, when user click on "Submit" button, to submit it's post, it can look up if there is ' sign, so to put \'  .
I also tried text without ' and SQL worked fine.

Comment: don't use execSQL, use [insert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))

Comment: @njzk2 thanks, i tried it out, it doesn't create issues anymore

Comment: glad to hear that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace your String with single quote with double quotes, it will work

```
yourString = yourString.replace(/\'/g,"''")
```

Comment: this does not address the root cause, which is that the op is creating sql queries by hand

Comment: @njzk2  op is asking: how you escape ' character in sql query string. Replacing problematic data value string works fine... Why downvote ?

Comment: the OP is trying to insert values in a SQL table. _ONE_ of the issues that they will encounter is escaping single quotes. That's far from being the only issue, and the right solution is definitely not to handle this specific problem, but to address the more general problem of how to correctly insert data in a table. Specifically, SQLite API in Android has methods to handle all escaping and data sanitation for you, not just single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by using [`insert()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)). Thanks to njzk2 comment.